# Remove the second point of a string and putting a 0 between characters

Tags: bash, shell, variable, string, version

I have semantic versioning string in a variable (X.Y.Z). I need to change that around, so that the second point disappears and I concatenate Y and Z separated by a 0 if Z is only one digit, or directly if Z has two digits.

So basically something like this:

```
1.5.0 -> 1.500
1.5.1 -> 1.501
1.4.7 -> 1.407
1.4.10 -> 1.410
1.4.24 -> 1.424
```

How could I do this using bash?

Comment: Is the string in a file? Filename? variable?

Comment: It's a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any POSIX shell, including `bash`, using the `${var##pattern}` and `${var%pattern}` ksh operators:

```
case $string in
  (*.*.*)
     minor=${string##*.}
     case $minor in
       (? | "") minor=0$minor
     esac
     string=${string%.*}$minor
esac
```

With bash-3.2+ specifically (and with bash 3.1 compatibility not enabled), you can also do:

```
if [[ $string =~ ^(.*\..*)\.([^.]*)([^.])$ ]]; then
  string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]:-0}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A expect=(
    [1.5.0]=1.500
    [1.5.1]=1.501
    [1.4.7]=1.407
    [1.4.10]=1.410
    [1.4.24]=1.424
)

new_version() {
    prefix=${1%%.*}
    suffix=${1##*.}
    middle=${1#*.}
    middle=${middle%.*}
    printf %s.%s%02d "$prefix" "$middle" "$suffix"

}

for old in "${!expect[@]}" ; do
    new=$(new_version $old)
    if [[ ${expect[$old]} == $new ]] ; then
        echo ok
    else
        echo not ok: in: $old expect: ${expect[$old]} got: $new
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v=1.5.1
( set -f; IFS=. split=( $v )
if [ ${#split[2]} -eq 1 ]
then 
  nv=${split[0]}.${split[1]}0${split[2]}
else
  nv=${split[0]}.${split[1]}${split[2]}
fi
printf "$nv" )
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, using `read` to split, and `printf` to zero-fill. With input from the variable `old` and output to `new` (at the cost of using some temporary variables):

```
old=1.4.24
IFS=. read -r a b c  <<< "$old"
printf -v new "%s.%s%02d" "$a" "$b" "$c"
echo "$old -> $new"
```

That should print `1.4.24 -> 1.424`

Answer (score 0):

Short **`awk`** solution:

Test cases:

```
ver_num="1.4.10"
awk -F'.' '{ printf "%d.%d%.2d", $1, $2, $3 }' <<<"$ver_num"
1.410
```

---

```
ver_num="1.5.0"
awk -F'.' '{ printf "%d.%d%.2d", $1, $2, $3 }' <<<"$ver_num"
1.500
```

---

```
ver_num="1.4.77"
awk -F'.' '{ printf "%d.%d%.2d", $1, $2, $3 }' <<<"$ver_num"
1.477
```